# python socket.connect timeout error in mulithread or multiprocess

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, timeout, multiprocessing

Like the following, I'd like to communicate with many PC's in a specific IP range.

```
My PC ---+------> Client A PC
         +------> Client B PC
         +------> Client C PC
         .................
         +------> Client Z PC
```

Because there are too many clients to communicate, I tried it by mulit-threading.
socket.connect() continuously produces time-out error.
If I try it in a single-thread, there's no problem.

I googled and found the below :

[Python Interpreter blocks Multithreaded DNS requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212716/python-interpreter-blocks-multithreaded-dns-requests)

saying that in some platform, socket module could be thread unsafe.

So I changed my code into multi-processing. However it still produces the same error.

In the following code sample, test_single() finishes normal.
test_mp() and test_mt() both make time-out error.

Have you ever experienced such abnormal behavior?
The testing environment is Windows XP SP3, python 2.5.4.
Also tried on python 2.6.6 and 2.7.0, same error.

```
import multiprocessing
import Queue
import socket
import threading

PROCESS_NUM = 5
PORT = 8888

def search_proc(ip):
    try:
        csock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        csock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        csock.settimeout(5.0)
        csock.connect((ip, PORT))
        csock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        csock.close()
        return ip, "ok"
    except socket.error, msg:
        return ip, "fail", msg

def mp_connect(ip_range):
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool( PROCESS_NUM )
    for output in pool.imap_unordered(search_proc, ip_range):
        print output

def test_mp():
    ip_range = []
    for i in range(256):
        ip_range.append("192.168.123.%d"%(i,))

    mp_connect(ip_range)

def test_mt():
    def search_thread(ip_queue):
        while True:
            ip = ip_queue.get()
            print search_proc(ip)
            ip_queue.task_done()
    ip_queue = Queue.Queue()

    for i in range(256):
        ip_queue.put("192.168.123.%d"%(i,))

    for i in range(PROCESS_NUM):
        th = threading.Thread(target=search_thread, args=(ip_queue,))
        th.setDaemon(True)
        th.start()

    ip_queue.join()

def test_single():
    ip_range = []
    for i in range(256):
        print search_proc("192.168.123.%d"%(i,))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    test_mp()
    #test_single()
    #test_mt()
```

Answer (score 5):

David Beazley has done some great research around the Python GIL and how that affects IO and multithreading. You can find information about his research [here](http://www.dabeaz.com/GIL/), [here](http://blip.tv/file/2232410).