# Python: How can I fix this code so it works on Windows?

Tags: python, multithreading, mechanize

```
import lxml.html
import mechanize, cookielib
import multiprocessing

browser = None

def download(i):
    link = 'www.google.com'
    response = browser.open(link)
    tree = lxml.html.parse(response)
    print tree
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    browser = mechanize.Browser()
    cookie_jar = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
    browser.set_cookiejar(cookie_jar)
    browser.set_handle_equiv(True)
    browser.set_handle_gzip(True)
    browser.set_handle_redirect(True)
    browser.set_handle_referer(False) #inicialmente estava on mas deve ser melhor off
    browser.set_handle_robots(False)
    browser.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)
    browser.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Ubuntu/11.04 maverick Firefox/4.0.1')]

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(None)
    tasks = range(8)
    r = pool.map_async(download, tasks)
    r.wait() # Wait on the results
```

If I remove the multiprocessing part, it works. If I don't call the browser inside the download function, it also works. However, it seems as if multiprocessing + mechanize is simply not working.

How can I fix this? It doesn't happen under linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the main process executes the gated `if __name__ == '__main__'` block. Since Windows lacks a fork system call, each process created in the pool needs its own browser. You can do this with an initializer function. For reference, see the `initializer` and `initargs` options of [multiprocessing.Pool](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing#module-multiprocessing.pool).

```
import lxml.html
import mechanize, cookielib
import multiprocessing as mp

def download(i):
    link = 'http://www.google.com'
    response = browser.open(link)
    tree = lxml.html.parse(response)
    print tree
    return 0

def init(count):
    global browser
    browser = mechanize.Browser()
    cookie_jar = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
    browser.set_cookiejar(cookie_jar)
    browser.set_handle_equiv(True)
    browser.set_handle_gzip(True)  #warning
    browser.set_handle_redirect(True)
    browser.set_handle_referer(False)
    browser.set_handle_robots(False)
    browser.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), 
                               max_time=1)
    browser.addheaders = [('User-agent', 
        'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:2.0.1) '
        'Gecko/20100101 Ubuntu/11.04 maverick Firefox/4.0.1')]

    count.value -= 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time
    count = mp.Value('I', mp.cpu_count())
    pool = mp.Pool(count.value, initializer=init, initargs=(count,))
    #wait until all processes are initialized
    while count.value > 0:
        time.sleep(0.1)

    tasks = range(8)
    r = pool.map_async(download, tasks)
    r.wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to:

- remove `browser = None`
  or
- move the code in the `__name__=="__main__"` into `main()` function and add `global browser` before `browser=mechanize.Browser()`
  or
- move code that initializes `browser` to an [`initializer`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool)

If your tasks are I/O bound then you don't necessarily need `multiprocessing` to make concurrent requests. For example, you could use `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`, `gevent`, `Twisted` instead.

Related: [Problem with multi threaded Python app and socket connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783735/problem-with-multi-threaded-python-app-and-socket-connections)