# Hit a url multiple times

Tags: python, url

I want to hit a URL N number of times in python. Currently I have been doing this using `webbrowser.open()`, but it is very slow and consumes a lot of memory. Any more efficient method?

Comment: @EnnoShioji: it is not a duplicate. Making **multiple** requests to **the same** url in an efficient manner is a different problem. You want [`ab`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html)-like tool rather than mere `curl`.

Comment: related: [Problem with multi threaded Python app and socket connections](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4783735/4279)

Comment: import requests

requests.get(url = "some_url")   --- run this in a loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

F.X.'s answer is almost certainly what you want.

But you asked about efficiency, and if you really want to be as efficient as possible, you can do better. The sooner you close the socket, the less you're wasting in CPU, memory, and bandwidth, both on your machine and on the web server.

Also, if you make multiple requests in parallel, while that won't save any resources on your machine (it'll actually waste some) or the server, it will probably finish faster. Is that what you're after?

Of course that raises the question of what exactly you mean by "hit a URL". Is it acceptable to just send the request and immediately shutdown? Or do you need to wait for at least the response line? For that matter, is it acceptable to make a `HEAD` request instead of a `GET`? Do you need realistic/useful headers?

Anyway, in order to do this, you'd want to drop down to a lower level. Most higher-level libraries don't give you any way to, e.g., close the socket before reading anything. But it's not that hard to craft HTTP requests.*

For example:

```
from contextlib import closing
from socket import create_connection
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, wait

host, port = 'www.example.com', 80
path = '/path/to/resource.html'

def spam_it():
    with closing(create_connection((host, port))) as sock:
        sock.sendall('GET {} HTTP/1.0\n\n'.format(path))

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=16) as executor:
    wait(executor.submit(spam_it) for _ in range(10000))
```

---

* Well, manually crafting HTTP requests is actually [quite involved](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt)… If you only need to craft a static, trivial one, do it yourself, but in general, you *definitely* want to use `urllib`, `requests`, or some other library.

Comment: +1. Though the example code won't work on Python 2 or Python 3 (use bytes literal for the data to send and mention that `futures` is 3rd party on Python 2)

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Urllib2.urlopen](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen)

```
import urllib2

for _ in range(10):
    urllib2.urlopen("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html)? As a standard rule of thumb, always look in the standard library first, there are tons of useful packages there.

Comment: You said `urllib`, but linked to `urllib2`. Otherwise, good answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
import urllib2

url = "http://www.google.com"
n = 8

for i in range(n):
  urllib.urlopen( url ).read()
```

You may wish to look into the [`requests` module](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) if you're eventually going to want to anything less trivial with HTTP requests.