# asyncio with map&reduce flavor and without flooding the event loop

Tags: python-3.x, scheduled-tasks, python-asyncio

I am trying to use asyncio in real applications and it doesn't go that
easy, a help of asyncio gurus is needed badly.

### Tasks that spawn other tasks without flooding event loop (Success!)

Consider a task like crawling the web starting from some "seeding" web-pages. Each
web-page leads to generation of new downloading tasks in exponential(!)
progression. However we don't want neither to flood the event loop nor to
overload our network. We'd like to control the task flow. This is what I
achieve well with modification of nice Maxime's solution proposed here:
https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2014-July/687823.html

### map & reduce (Fail)

Well, but I'd need as well a very natural thing, kind of map() & reduce()
or functools.reduce() if we are on python3 already. That is, I'd need to
call a "summarizing" function for all the downloading tasks completed on
links from a page. This is where i fail :(

I'd propose an oversimplified but still a nice test to model the use case:
Let's use fibonacci function implementation in its ineffective form.
That is, let the coro_sum() be applied in reduce() and coro_fib be what we apply with
map(). Something like this:

```py
@asyncio.coroutine
def coro_sum(x):
    return sum(x)

@asyncio.coroutine
def coro_fib(x):
    if x < 2:
        return 1
    res_coro =
executor_pool.spawn_task_when_arg_list_of_coros_ready(coro=coro_sum,

 arg_coro_list=[coro_fib(x - 1), coro_fib(x - 2)])
    return res_coro
```

So that we could run the following tests.

Test #1 on one worker:

```
executor_pool = ExecutorPool(workers=1)
executor_pool.as_completed( coro_fib(x) for x in range(20) )
```

Test #2 on two workers:

```
executor_pool = ExecutorPool(workers=2)
executor_pool.as_completed( coro_fib(x) for x in range(20) )
```

It would be very important that both each coro_fib() and coro_sum()
invocations are done via a Task on some worker, not just spawned implicitly
and unmanaged!

It would be cool to find asyncio gurus interested in this very natural goal.
Your help and ideas would be very much appreciated.

best regards

Valery

Comment: @Joren, strange... it looks like links aren't permanent there. Anyway updated.

Answer (score 1):

There are [multiple ways to compute fibonacci series asynchroniously](https://github.com/zed/txfib/blob/master/fibonacci.py#L229). First, check that the explosive variant fails in your case:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def coro_sum(summands):
    return sum(summands)

@asyncio.coroutine
def coro_fib(n):
    if   n == 0: s = 0
    elif n == 1: s = 1
    else:
        summands, _ = yield from asyncio.wait([coro_fib(n-2), coro_fib(n-1)])
        s = yield from coro_sum(f.result() for f in summands)
    return s
```

You could replace `summands` with:

```
a = yield from coro_fib(n-2) # don't return until its ready
b = yield from coro_fib(n-1)
s = yield from coro_sum([a, b])
```

In general, to prevent the exponential growth, you could use `asyncio.Queue` ([synchronization via communication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26638490/4279)), `asyncio.Semaphore` ([synchonization using mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20722204/4279)) primitives.