# how to crawl and process (cpu intensive) thousands of URLs using gevent and threading?

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, urllib2, gevent

I've been playing with tornado, twisted, gevent, grequests in order to get the best performance in the process of fetching 50k urls.

The process I want to create:

- parse all urls into a set (avoid duplicates)
- for each url: check existence of the url in a whitelist redis db (contains millions of urls)
- download the urls using gevent/other async libraries
- insert the fetched content into a queue
- in parallel: listen to the queue with threads
- process (intensive regex) the queue items using threads
- save the output to a MySQL DB
- for each url update the whitelist redis db

I'm going to process millions urls a day, I started implementing this but got into a few problems;

firstly, populating a queue with the results I get from the async-crawler consumes to much memory - I need to address it, what would be a good practice?
secondly, I'm having hard time synchronizing both threading and the gevent crawler, how to I download asyncly and process while populating the queue with results?

Or, How do I synchronize the async-crawler with the threading code that process the response from the async-crawler?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[gevent, twisted, asyncio should handle 50k urls just fine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4783735/4279).

To avoid consuming too much memory and to synchronize the processes that download and process urls, you could set the maximum size on the corresponding queues: if the downloading happens too fast; it will block on `queue.put()` when it reaches its maximum capacity.

Green threads would be useless for a parallel regex processing. Ordinary Python threads that use real OS threads would be useless here if GIL is not released during the regex processing. `re` does not release GIL. [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module can release GIL in some cases.

If you use `re` module; you might want to create a processes pool instead of threads where the number of processes ~number of cpus on the host.

Beware of how you use MySQL, Redis (you might need a green driver for some usage scenarios).

Comment: should I use gevent's queue or threading's queue? how would you suggest using Redis?

Comment: @YSY: 1. if you want to block the producer thread that fetches the urls (stop the world (the event loop)); then use `Queue.Queue` (unpatched; blocking API) to allow the consumer threads to catch up.  2. start with the simplest approach (redis with patched sockets: green driver) -- the code looks identical to the synchronous single-thread case. Measure the time performance and change the approach if necessary.