# Multithreading in python using queue

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, python-multithreading

I am quite new to Python and I need to implement multithreading in my code.

I have a huge .csv file (million lines) as my input. I read the line,  make a rest request for each line, do some processing on each line and write the output into another file. The ordering of lines in input/output file does  matter . Right now I am doing this line by line. 
I want to run the same code, but in parallel, i.e read 20 lines of input from .csv file and make the rest call in parallel so that my program is faster.

I have been reading up on http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html, but I read about the python GIL issue which says the code will not run faster even after multithreading. 
Is there any other way to achieve multithreading in a simple way?

Comment: your code should benefit from threading because it is IO bound, (the http requests are the slow part of the code), there are tons of tutorials out there on how to use threading for HTTP requests in python

Answer (score 2):

Can you break the .csv file into multiple smaller files? If you can, then you could have another program running multiple versions of your processer.

Say the files were all named *file1*, *file2*, etc. and your processer took the filename as an argument. You could have:

```
import subprocess
import os
import signal

for i in range(1,numfiles):
    program = subprocess.Popen(['python'], "processer.py", "file" + str(i))
    pid = program.pid

    #if you need to kill the process:
    os.kill(pid, signal.SIGINT)
```

Comment: Yea, I can break my file into smaller files , but the order of input/output should be preserved. Can that be achieved ?

Comment: Ahh, sorry I misread your question and thought order did not matter. My method would not preserve the order unless you had an intermediary step of processed files and then combined the processed files in order of file number. Maybe @J.F.Sebastian's answer will help on that front.

Answer (score 1):

Python releases GIL on IO. If most of the time is spent doing rest requests; you could use threads to speed up processing:

```
try:
    from gevent.pool import Pool # $ pip install gevent
    import gevent.monkey; gevent.monkey.patch_all() # patch stdlib
except ImportError: # fallback on using threads
    from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

import urllib2    

def process_line(url):
    try:
        return urllib2.urlopen(url).read(), None
    except EnvironmentError as e:
        return None, e

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as file, open('output.txt', 'wb') as outfile:
    pool = Pool(20) # use 20 concurrent connections
    for result, error in pool.imap_unordered(process_line, file):
        if error is None:
            outfile.write(result)
```

If input/output order should be the same; you could use `imap` instead of `imap_unordered`.

If your program is CPU-bound; you could use `multiprocessing.Pool()` that creates multiple processes instead.

See also [Python Interpreter blocks Multithreaded DNS requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1212716/4279)

[This answer shows how to create a thread pool manually using threading + Queue modules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9874484/4279).